# MySQL: matching records that don't exist

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
Customer
+---+-----------+
|ID |VoicemailID|

Voicemail
+---+----------+
|ID |CustomerID|
```

`Voicemail.CustomerID` releates to `Customer.ID`, and visa versa.

How would I select rows from the Customer Table, where `Customer.VoicemailID` is no longer a valid record in the Vo`icemail` table?

It's a situation where the record used to exist in the `Voicemail` table, but has since been deleted. I now need to find all records in the `Customer` table that have the `VoicemailID` of a non-existing record.

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.ID, Customer.VoicemailID
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Voicemail ON Customer.VoicemailID <> Voicemail.ID
```

However I belive it returns results I want, mixed in with results where the Voicemail instance still exists.

Comment: I'm aware of foreign keys. Unfortunately the original table designer didn't make use of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the result you want:

```
SELECT Customer.ID, Customer.VoicemailID
FROM Customer
   LEFT JOIN Voicemail ON Voicemail.ID = Customer.VoicemailID
WHERE Voicemail.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: I had too append `AND Customer.Voicemail IS NOT NULL` as I was only after the instances that had a number. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with the `LEFT JOIN`.  But you need to look for a match and then return when it fails:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.VoicemailID
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN
     Voicemail v
     ON c.VoicemailID = v.ID
WHERE v.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery and look for rows that aren't there. Check the syntax for `WHERE NOT EXISTS` on MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM otherTable 
                 WHERE table.id = otherTable.someField )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  select VoicemailID
  from Customer
  where VoicemailID not in (select id from Voicemail)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery like this

```
select * from customer a
 where not exists (select 1 from voicemail b 
                    where b.id = a.voicemailid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct query in [PHP: 5.5.3], I'm using phpMyAdmin in Xampp 1.8.3.

```
SELECT * FROM Customer 
WHERE Customer.VoicemailID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Voicemail)
```

Comment: Please add elaborate a little on your answer so it will contain some context as apposed to it being code-only.